# Perform X509 Certificate Revocation Check without installing certificate into certificate store

Tags: .net, x509certificate

I’m looking at comparing a user certificate to a root certificate. If I install the root certificate in the windows store everything works fine. However for my application installing the certificate in the store won’t be possible.

When I don’t install the certificate I get the expected UntrustedRoot status, but I also get RevocationOffline and RevocationStatusUnknown.

From what I’ve read, revocation checking is only performed on a chain that ends in a self-signed certificate in the trusted root store. Is there another way to do the revocation check after calling `chain.Build`? Or is there anything I can setup before `Build` so that it still performs the check with an untrusted root? I am trying to avoid using thrid party libraries if possible.

I have

```
X509Chain chain = new X509Chain
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain
chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;

chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(root);
isValid = chain.Build(certificate);

// Check Byte Code
var chainRoot = chain.ChainElements[chain.ChainElements.Count - 1].Certificate;
isValid = isValid && chainRoot.RawData.SequenceEqual(root.RawData);
```

**Update:** In .Net 5 there is now the option to use a CustomTrustStore. If you don't want to install the root certificate in the Windows store. To do this change the trust mode to CustomRootTrust and add the root certificate to the CustomTrustStore.

```
chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust
chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(certificate);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with pure .Net, you need to use CryptoAPI interop. Basically, you need to call `CertCreateCertificateChainingEngine` function. The function accepts `pConfig` parameter which is a pointer to a `CERT_CHAIN_ENGINE_CONFIG` structure where you configure a set of trusted roots in `hRestrictedRoots` field. Configure other fields if necessary. After  `CertCreateCertificateChainingEngine` function call, you will get a pointer to a `HCERTCHAINENGINE` which you pass to a `CertGetCertificateChain` function as a `hChainEngine` parameter.